# How to get links to all pdf files from removable storage(SD Card) of android in java?

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard

I am unable to fetch pdf files from removable storage(SD Card).

I have successfully fetched all the links to pdfs in the external storage using the following method

```
    public String findBooks() {

        String pdf = ".pdf";
        String epub = ".epub";

        File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        Queue<File> toVisit = new PriorityQueue<>(); 
        toVisit.add(dir);
        String pdfs = "";
        int pdfCount = 0;

        if (toVisit.size() != 0) {
          while(true){
              File file = toVisit.remove();
              File[] tmpList = file.listFiles();
              int i;
              for(i = 0; i < tmpList.length; i++){
                if (tmpList[i].isDirectory()) {
                    toVisit.add(tmpList[i]);
                } 
                else if (tmpList[i].getName().endsWith(pdf) || tmpList[i].getName().endsWith(epub) ){
                    pdfs += tmpList[i].toString() + ",";
                    pdfCount += 1;
                }
              }

              if(toVisit.size() == 0){
                Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), "End of search: "+ String.valueOf(pdfCount), 0).show();
                break;
              }
          }
        }

      return pdfs;
    }
```

Comment: For getting the path to a removable micro sd card have a look at the second item returned by `getExternalFilesDirs()`. The rest of your code can stay the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have successfully fetched all the links to pdfs in external SD card using the following method

That code is working with [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/11/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

> I guess I should be able to use the same method to fetch pdfs from internal storage as well

No, because you have no access to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), other than the directories set aside specifically for your app (e.g., `getFilesDir()` on `Context`).

Comment: @peter That was immensely clarifying! Thank you very much. But then how do I access the pdfs on removable storage

Comment: @CodeNinja: You don't, particularly on newer versions of Android. Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and let the user pick the PDF from the user's available local and cloud storage options.